# Как вызвать метод?

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в том, как вызвать метод, который привязан к событию нажатия кнопки. Вроде звучит просто, но я не знаю, как. С JS пришлось столкнуться только сейчас.

Есть дашборд (http://play.grafana.org/#/dashboard/db/grafana-play-home), на странице есть кнопка "Zoom out". Я хочу вызвать этот метод в другом месте, но, увы, не знаю, как. Вот это место на странице:

```
<a class="small" ng-click="zoom(2)">Zoom Out</a>
```

Если в консоль ввести "zoom(2)", то получаю ошибку "ReferenceError: zoom is not defined". Как достучаться до этого метода?

Comment: angular же? код приведите.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите вызвать эту функцию не из кода ангуляр приложение, то можно использовать [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) и его метод `scope`

Например так:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('gf-time-picker a.small')) //получили элемент клик которого хотим вызвать
       .scope() //получили скоп привязанный к этому элементу
       // для случая из поста
       .zoom(2) //вызываем функцию с необходимыми параметрами

      // для случая использованного на сайте: используется `controller As` синтаксис
      .ctrl //получаем ссылку на контроллер, название зависит от указанного в директиве.
      .zoom(2) //вызываем функцию с необходимыми параметрами
```

Если функцию необходимо вызвать внутри ангуляра, то в данном случае это зависти от структуры, которая используется, возможны варианты от простого вызова функции в нужном месте, до, например, посылки события через `$emit` или `$broadcast`

Answer (score 0):

Может, попробовать [триггернуть](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) событие `click` на этом элементе? Как-то типа:

```
$( 'a.small').each( function(){
    if( $( this).text == 'Zoom Out') $( this).trigger( 'click');
});
```