# Что делать, если модель в angular изменяется посредством сторонней библиотеки?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, яндекс-карты

Суть такая: используется "Яндекс.карты",
На input вешается яндексовский обработчик, для реализации "умного поиска". То есть, когда пользователь вводит адрес ему вываливается список подсказок с полным адресом. Кликая на одну из них, он выбирает адрес.
При этом то, что он вводит в ручную в input конечно же сразу попадает в модель, а вот его выбор из списка в модель не попадает, если только не вернуться в input и не нажать хотя бы пробел, чтобы обновить данные модели.
Как это обработать, учитывая, что input находится в изолированной директиве и данные нужны в родительском контроллере?

Comment: вероятно, можно принудительно обновить модель через `scope.$apply` в обработчике события `select`, если мы говорим про `SelectView` из Yandex Maps Javascript API

Comment: да, речь о suggestView

Comment: то есть, если я ставлю обработчик в link, то в оброаботчике пишу
scope.$apply(()={scope.model=...})?

Comment: @OlegAgapitov, возможно [дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361059/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4/466494#466494)

Answer (score 1):

Повесить на этот инпут обработчик `onchange` и делать там `dirty-check` посредством `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?